# What’s the probability that out of a $100$ randomly selected people in Belgium that at least one drinks milk?

Tags: probability

$97\%$ of the people in Belgium drink milk. What’s the probability that out of a $100$ randomly selected people in Belgium that at least one drinks milk?

Comment: What’s the probability that out of a 100 randomly selected people in Belgium **no one** drinks milk?

Comment: Ahhhh thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If there are $P$ people in Belgium, it is
$$1-\frac{\frac3{100}P}{P}\cdot\frac{\frac3{100}P-1}{P-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{\frac3{100}P-99}{P-99}$$

If $P$ is big enough, you can assume Rishi's answer for practical purposes.

Comment: There were approximately [11.4 million people in Belgium in 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgium).

Answer (score 0):

Required probability is = 1 - prob(no one drinks milk)

$$=1-\bigg({3 \over 100}\bigg)^{100} $$

Which is Almost 100% .

For fun even if  97% doesn't drink milk , there are 95.24 % chances that at least one person from 100 drinks milk. Now you can imagine how close your answer to 100% is.